# How to retrieve data from a attached zip file in Blackberry application?

Tags: blackberry, compression, zip, gzip, zlib

I am using eclipse to build application for Blackberry. I attached a zip file with my application. Please help me, I don't know how to retrieve data form the zip file in application development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In BlackBerry we can use two compression standarts: [GZip](http://www.gzip.org/) and [ZLib](http://www.zlib.net/). 
Choose one, then compress your file and add to project. 
Then you should be able to open it as an resource. 
After that decompress it with [GZIPInputStream](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/net/rim/device/api/compress/GZIPInputStream.html) or [ZLibInputStream](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/net/rim/device/api/compress/ZLibInputStream.html) accordingly.

Example (uncompress and print text from test.gz attached to project):

```
try
{
    InputStream inputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("test.gz");
    GZIPInputStream gzis = new GZIPInputStream(inputStream);
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

    int i;
    while ((i = gzis.read()) != -1)           
    {
        sb.append((char)i);
    }

    String data = sb.toString();
    add(new RichTextField(data));
    gzis.close();
}
catch(IOException ioe)
{
    //do something here
}
```