# How to unzip files in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, unzip, compression

I'm developing an app that manages a file zip with directories and files. I must know how to unzip these files in order to create in local the same structure as in the zip file.

Thanks in advance :)

Sergio

Comment: possible duplicate 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357640/how-to-retrieve-data-from-a-attached-zip-file-in-blackberry-application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no native APIs on BlackBerry that support ZIP archives.  You may have to Google around for third party packages or libraries to do this for you.